# subtract date based on day in oracle

Tags: oracle

Based on below query when part is not work,

```
select case when to_char(sysdate,'Day')  =  'Friday'  then trunc(SYSDATE) - 3 else trunc(SYSDATE) - 2   end as tempdate from dual
```

any help?

Answer (score 2):

`TO_CHAR` puts trailing spaces. you may add a `TRIM`

```
SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN TRIM(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'Day')) = 'Friday' THEN trunc(SYSDATE) - 3
            ELSE trunc(SYSDATE) - 2
        END
    AS tempdate
FROM
    dual
```

You may also use `Fm` format specifier

`to_char (sysdate, 'FmDay')` to avoid TRIM

or to avoid `NLS_` parameter issues

```
TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'FmDay', 'nls_date_language=english')
```

Comment: Thank you, i missed th trip, i didn't realize that it requires